# Testing :id routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, testing, mocha.js

How can I test routes with :id into it.

For example, we have suppose a route like this

```
Router.get('/:id/profile
```

Now, I want to do a test case, the example scenario I saw from someone's else code was that he was passing a string of numbers (probably user ID or something)

Being a total beginner who have been asked to test something, how can I find that string which I can send when testing something.

For example here

```
describe('Admin users API testing', () => {
    it('GET /admin/users/:id/activityLog', (done) => {
        request(URL)
            .get('/admin/users/5a82b1a61dab4b54fj01f212e/activityLog')
            .set('accept', '/application/json')
```

We are sending request to

```
it('GET /admin/users/:id/activityLog
```

Which then looks like this

```
 .get('/admin/users/5a82b1a61dab4b54fj01f212e/activityLog')
```

inside the above get request we have, something like this

```
5a82b1a61dab4b54fj01f212e
```

So my question is how do the person doing testing knows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of integration testing. Firstly, we must prepare the test data. If using database, it means that we need to insert them before running the test.

In your case, we must insert activity log for user with id `5a82b1a61dab4b54fj01f212e` in database. So later, you can expect to get this data back in the test. It should be applied with other users we want to test.

It should be:

```
describe('Admin users API testing', () => {
  before(() => {
    return insertTestData(); // insert test data to database, contain activity log for user 5a82b1a61dab4b54fj01f212e
  });

  it('GET /admin/users/:id/activityLog', (done) => {
    return request(URL)
      .get('/admin/users/5a82b1a61dab4b54fj01f212e/activityLog')
      .set('accept', '/application/json')
      .then(response => {
        expect(response).to.eql([{ // we can match the response with test data 
          log_id: 1,
          activity_name: 'test'
        }])
      });
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Before testing begins, you need to seed your database with some data. You can pass this id-string along with this seed-data, and use this same id while testing.

Or

If you are adding this record during one of your test cases, then you need to preserve the id-string in some variable to be used in this test case.